# Python-How to match keywords to text?

Tags: nlp, keyword

I want to match keywords with novel texts and rank them in order of relevancy.
For instance, if the keywords are “pain” and “scar,” the desired output is:

Ranked 1st place:
“It's so hard to forget pain, but it's even harder to remember sweetness. We have no scar to show for happiness. We learn so little from peace.”
― Chuck Palahniuk, Diary

Ranked 2nd place:
“The marks humans leave are too often scars.”
― John Green, The Fault in Our Stars

I am currently thinking about turning those keywords to vectors and match with words in the novel, and the novel excerpts are ranked from high relevancy to low relevancy. However, since I am relatively new to programming, I do not know if this idea is feasible, and if it is, how to write the code. I have also looked through a few related questions here on stackoverflow but did not completely understand the answers. Can anyone give me some directions?

Comment: So you want to rank text snippets based on keywords with rating scores: the keyword *pain* would have the score 1 and the keyword *scar* would have the score 2 and so on. The list with keywords and their rankings already exists somewhere. Is this understanding correct?

Answer (score 0):

You can spaCy, which is a pre-trained English model that can parse text and extract linguistic features. Then, it processes the input text using the nlp object, which creates a Doc object containing a sequence of Token objects.

As an example,

```
import spacy

nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')

text = "It's so hard to forget pain, but it's even harder to remember sweetness. We have no scar to show for happiness. We learn so little from peace."

doc = nlp(text)

keywords = []
for token in doc:
    if token.pos_ in ['NOUN', 'ADJ'] and not token.is_stop:
        keywords.append(token.text)

print(keywords)
```

To learn more about spaCy:
https://www.machinelearningplus.com/nlp/keyword-extraction-in-python/.